# Prisma in Backend Directory or Frontend Directory?

Tags: node.js, next.js, prisma, next-auth

Where's the right project directory to put Prisma ?
Backend Directory/Server or Frontend Directory/Server ?

Going for an Webapp with Nextjs, NextAuth(MagicLink), Prisma and PostgreSQL.

Every example that I see people use prisma inside Next folder which is frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can separate frontend and backend to two different servers and `Prisma` should ideally be in the backend.

Here is a [blog post](https://dev.to/prisma/passwordless-authentication-with-next-js-prisma-and-next-auth-5g8g) which describes the best practices and a demo to create web app using NextAuth and Prisma.

Here is an official [prisma-example](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/rest-nextjs-api-routes-auth) to get you started with NextAuth and Prisma and also demonstrated the ideal practices which should be followed.

Comment: But isn't Prisma in the same directory of the frontend in those projects ?